Linux SAMBA Denied Connection from Windows 11 client
I have a small aarch64 embedded Linux board running kernel 5.15 and a Windows 11 machine. I do not have the ability of installing samba natively on this device. However, I do have a docker engine and the ability to load and run containers.
I want to expose a samba directory from the Linux machine to my locally networked Windows 11 machine.
I found a container image on docker hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/crazymax/samba.
Based on the documentation, I setup the config file to look like this:
cat config.yml
auth:
  - user: foo
    group: foo
    uid: 1000
    gid: 1000
    password: bar

global:
  - "force user = foo"
  - "force group = foo"

sambashare:
  - name: foo
    path: /samba/foo
    browsable: yes
    readonly: no
    guestok: no
    validusers: foo
    writelist: foo
    veto: no
    hidefiles: /_*/
    recycle: yes

I ensured the proper ports were open and ran the container with the following commands:
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
docker run -d --network host --privileged -v "/data/data:/data" --name samba crazymax/samba

The docker logs look as shown below:
docker logs -f samba
[s6-init] making user provided files available at /var/run/s6/etc...exited 0.
[s6-init] ensuring user provided files have correct perms...exited 0.
[fix-attrs.d] applying ownership & permissions fixes...
[fix-attrs.d] done.
[cont-init.d] executing container initialization scripts...
[cont-init.d] 01-config.sh: executing...
Setting timezone to UTC
Initializing files and folders
Setting global configuration
Creating user foo/foo (1000:1000)
Add global option: force user = foo
Add global option: force group = foo
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed by GnuTLS (e.g. NTLM as a compatibility fallback)

WARNING: The 'netbios name' is too long (max. 15 chars).

# Global parameters
[global]
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

        disable netbios = Yes
        disable spoolss = Yes
        dns proxy = No
        local master = No
        map to guest = Bad User
        pam password change = Yes
        printcap name = /dev/null
        security = USER
        server role = standalone server
        server services = s3fs, rpc, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbindd, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate
        server string = Docker Samba Server
        smb1 unix extensions = No
        smb ports = 445
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        winbind scan trusted domains = Yes
        fruit:time machine = yes
        fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
        fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
        fruit:veto_appledouble = no
        fruit:posix_rename = yes
        fruit:model = MacSamba
        fruit:metadata = stream
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775
        force create mode = 0664
        force directory mode = 0775
        force group = foo
        force user = foo
        hosts allow = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16
        hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
        printing = bsd
        strict locking = No
        vfs objects = fruit streams_xattr
        wide links = Yes
[cont-init.d] 01-config.sh: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 02-svc-smbd.sh: executing...
[cont-init.d] 02-svc-smbd.sh: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 03-svc-wsdd2.sh: executing...
[cont-init.d] 03-svc-wsdd2.sh: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] ~-socklog: executing...
[cont-init.d] ~-socklog: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] done.
[services.d] starting services
[services.d] done.
smbd version 4.19.6 started.
Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2023
Denied connection from 172.1.17.3 (172.1.17.3)
Denied connection from 172.1.17.3 (172.1.17.3)
Denied connection from 172.1.17.3 (172.1.17.3)
Denied connection from 172.1.17.3 (172.1.17.3)

I then installed Ubuntu on Windows 11 WSL. I ensured to install the proper cifs/samba packages and made sure I could successfully ping the Linux machine (located at 172.1.17.1).
The error comes when I try to mount the Linux samba share from Windows WSL. I can see on the docker logs output from Linux that it is seeing the incoming connection but 'denying' it (Note this message above: Denied connection from 172.1.17.3).
I cannot figure out how to get it to mount properly, or why the connection is denied. Below are some of the commands I have tried. What can I do to get this mount to work?
   sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,vers=3.0 //172.1.17.1/sambashare /media/share
   sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,vers=1.0 //172.1.17.1/sambashare /media/share
   sudo mount -t cifs //172.1.17.1/sambashare /media/share
   sudo mount -t cifs guest //172.1.17.1/sambashare /media/share
   sudo mount.cifs --options guest //172.1.17.1/sambashare /media/share/
   sudo mount.cifs --options user=foo,pass=foo //172.1.17.1/sambashare /media/share/
   sudo mount.cifs --options vers=1.0,user=foo,pass=foo //172.1.17.1/sambashare /media/share/

This mount also fails if I try to use Windows itself to mount the drive:


Your logs say:
        hosts allow = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16

Denied connection from 172.1.17.3 (172.1.17.3)

That is, the Docker container pre-configures Samba to only allow connections from 'private' IP addresses, and your client's address 172.1.17.3 is not within any of those ranges.
It is actually a public address owned by AT&T and assigned to someone in Texas, US, so unless you're that person, you shouldn't be using such addresses for your LAN. (If you are that person, you can edit the hosts allow = smb.conf option.)
For reference, the range 172.16.0.0/12 starts at 172.16.0.0 and ends at 172.31.255.255.

Thank you this worked!
